# When changing to another radio button - remove class

Tags: jquery

In example i have 3 radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="reason" id="1" value="1" class="trigger reason" data-target=".safety, .hygiene, .code, .food" />
<input type="radio" name="reason" id="2" value="2" class="trigger reason" data-target=".safety, .hygiene" />
<input type="radio" name="reason" id="3" value="3" class="trigger reason" data-target=".safety, .code, .food" />
```

If i click a radio button a variable amount of checkboxes are showing on the screen.
This code is making this happen:

```
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
    var $showDiv = $('.showdiv').hide();
    $('.trigger').change(function(){
        $showDiv.hide();
        $($(this).data('target')).show();
});
});
```

Some checkboxes are shown under more than one radio button.

I have styled my checkboxes with some default bootstrap 3 jQuery methods so my checkboxes are looking like a button with text

```
<div class="hygiene showdiv col-md-2 col-sm-2">
  <label class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="termLabel" data-toggle="buttons">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" name="achygiene" value="1" id="achygiene"> <?php echo $lrow[13]; ?>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="safety showdiv col-md-2 col-sm-2">
  <label class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="termLabel" data-toggle="buttons">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" name="acsecurity" value="1" id="acsecurity"> <?php echo $lrow[13]; ?>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="defence showdiv col-md-2 col-sm-2">
  <label class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="termLabel" data-toggle="buttons">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" name="acdefence" value="1" id="acdefence"> <?php echo $lrow[13]; ?>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="food showdiv col-md-2 col-sm-2">
  <label class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="termLabel" data-toggle="buttons">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" name="acfire" value="1" id="acfire"> <?php echo $lrow[13]; ?>
  </label>
</div>
```

Now when i chose a radio button and i check the checkboxes that appear but after that i see that i have chosen the wrong radio button and click on the right one. Some of the checkboxes are still checked + the active state (class) that is automaticaly added by bootstrap when you check a checkbox (different color) stays active.

I want to reset all checkboxes and remove that active class when i choose another radio button.

this is what i have tried but that doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[name=reason]:radio").click(function () {
        $('#registrationForm input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $('.showdiv label').removeClass('active');      
    });
});
```

could someone help a little hand with this? I don't understand why this isn't working (i am not so good with jQuery)

Comment: maybe try $('#registrationForm input:checkbox').attr('checked', ' '); and for the class maybe you can change the class of the element, so: $('.showdiv label').attr('class', 'other_class');

Comment: thanks Abdul, but that didn't work i fixed it myself instead by doing `$("input[name=reason]:radio").click(function () {`using this: `$("#au, #ma, #pi, #vi, #de").change(function () {` (using the id's of the radio button)

Comment: I see, I just thought of something else, you could also try this in the future, using "prop" instead of "attr"  $('#registrationForm input:checkbox').prop('checked', 'false');